# React Scripts V5 throwing Errors

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-typescript, react-scripts

I have a React App working on version 17, recently I upgraded to version 18, I upgraded the `react` , `react dom` and other relevant packages as well.
My `react-scripts` version was `^4.0.3` and when i run `react-scripts start` it ran sucessfully without any issues

In the next step I upgraded the `react-scripts` to version 5 and node version to 14. And when i tried to start the app it gives random errors from diffrent files including `.svg` files and from `node_modules` as well

---

**In Short**

```
React 18

Node 12

react-scripts 4.0.3
```

works fine

---

```
React 18

Node 14

react-scripts 5
```

Give errors

---

Comment: Delete your node modules and package-lock.json, and then try npm i

Comment: reinstall all node modules

Comment: @RitikBanger I tried it , but didn't worked , Thanks you

Comment: @ShahVipul Sorry it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a common problem in react-scripts v5. Here you can find a temporary solution: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11770

I had the following error when using SVG files which have animation:

ERROR in ./src/assets/file.svg

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js)

Using file-loader worked for me.

```
import yourSvg from "!file-loader!/assets/file.svg"
```